# Putting and operator in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, operators

```
public void displayData(String [] names, int []scores, char [] grades){
        for (String name : names && char grade : grades)
            System.out.println(name + "\t");
            System.out.print(grade);
```

Above is my code.  I need to put an and operator in the for loop but the code above is not correct. Please help. I will give additional details if needed.

Comment: Josh, I'll comment here, since I'm not answering your question directly. You might be better served by passing in an ArrayList of a custom "Student" type object that has fields for name, score and grade. Then you can use the new enhanced-for loop, and just get the fields from each Student object. The way you have the method defined now, there will need to be a lot of error checking to make sure arrays are the same length, and the the indexes in each array match up.

Comment: Could you guys upvote this post? I need 3 more reputation to chat which I desperatley need!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the arrays are parallel (all of the same length, with the value in the grades array at index *i* being the grade of the student in the names array at index *i*), you probably could just re-write the loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; ++i) {
  System.out.println(names[i] + "\t" + grades[i]);
}
```

Also, try to avoid multiple System.out.print statements one after another, as each requires a call to the operating system which slows your application down a bit, because the entire program much stop while the operating system handles your request to print the string. Concatenate (stick together with '`+`') strings where possible, instead.

Comment: please avoid confusing the OP by teaching him / her lots of different lessons at the same time.  Besides, the String concatenation is a MICRO-optimization, and probably makes **no perceptible difference** in the OP's use-case.

Comment: I hardly think so. Every time you print a string, the operating system needs to service the request while your program waits. The OS has better things to do. It might not matter here, but designing for scalability is always good practice. In a loop that executes thousands of times, this will make plenty of difference.

Comment: it is HIGHLY UNLIKELY that this loop will be executed thousands of times.  Look at it.  Infer the context.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex! This is perfect and with a few tweaking was just what I was looking for.  And Stephen, I am a beginning CS major so basic is better lol. But thanks for your concerns

Comment: @StephanC What he learns here is what he'll write in the future. Why not learn good habits from the start?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code it looks like you need this:

```
public void displayData(String [] names, int []scores, char [] grades) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + "\t");
        System.out.print(grades[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind I am dumb, I didn't close in brackets for multiple arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the new-style `for` loop to iterate over two arrays / collections in parallel.  You need to use an old-style `for` loop with an explicit index variable.  For example:

```
public void displayData(String [] names, int []scores, char [] grades) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(names[i] + "\t");
        System.out.print(grades[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am a begginer CS major so I dont know what the old style for is.  Is there an easy way to print these two arrays with for loops?

Comment: @Josh - no, there isn't.  But this is not hard either.

Comment: @Stephen C Try to avoid multiple System.out.print* statements if you can. Each requires a call to the operating system, which is a really unnecessary overhead.
@Josh My answer uses the 'old style'.

Comment: @citizen conn - please explain.  AFAIK, the '&&' in the loop was the OP's attempt at saying "and this one as well".  Of course, that's not what the '&&' operator actually means.  Hence, the solution does not involve an '&&' operator.

Comment: @AlexWebr - please avoid confusing the OP by teaching him / her lots of different lessons at the same time.

Comment: What if grades.length > names.length. Right now your loop will stop when its done iterating through all the names, but not all the grades. Theoretically they would have to match, but maybe they wont and you could try catch the IndexOutOfBoundsException inside the loop.

Comment: @citizen conn - You should NOT catch the exception IMO.  If the arrays are different size then the **programmer** has made a mistake in his assumption that they should be the same ... and this is a BUG.  The correct thing to do is to let the application die with a stack trace and / or log the failure to the application.  Attempting to catch the exception at THIS point is at best a waste of time.  At worst it will obscure the real problem (the bug) and make it harder to diagnose.

Comment: If the OP is having trouble with looping constructs, I have a feeling exception handling is a little much for now ;)
@citizen: my thoughts exactly. +1

Comment: meh, I kinda disagree. In this case it probably means the programmer messed up, but he's asking about operands in for loops and that's what I've seen operands in for loops for -- looping through arrays that might be of a different size. In more complex applications this could totally be valid.

Comment: Why not add some JDBC code to the exception to log errors to a database? ;)

Comment: Guys, could you upvote this post? I need 3 more reputation so I can chat...Which I desperatley need!!

Comment: @Josh, why not earn it like everybody else?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length && i < grades.length; i++){
    System.out.println(names[i]);
    System.out.println(grades[i]);
}
```

**Edit:** It might help to clarify what the user is asking: how to get his code to work, or how to put an operand in a for loop. In the case of the latter, the purpose is arguable, but I have seen it used to loop through arrays of different lengths. Question that practice you may, but that's what one could use it for. In the case of the former, he probably should just use a traditional for loop like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    System.out.println(names[i]);
    System.out.println(grades[i]);
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid multiple System.out.print* statements if you can. Each requires a call to the operating system, which is a really unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @AlexWebr - Thx. I usually use it just for illustration, but maybe I'll use comments instead.

Comment: @AlexWebr - please avoid confusing the OP by teaching him / her lots of different lessons at the same time. Besides, the String concatenation is a MICRO-optimization, and probably makes no perceptible difference in the OP's use-case.

Comment: @Stephen It's bad style. There's nothing wrong with writing smart code, especially when it's this easy.

Comment: @AlexWebr - the OP needs to learn the Java syntax BEFORE worrying about style nit-picks.  And this the a *real nit-pick* from a stylistic point of view.

Comment: It's not a style choice, it's simply poor code. Everytime you print, an interrupt happens. There's no reason to call the OS more than you need to.

Comment: @AlexWebr Stack Overflow isn't a Java compiler. These are code snippets, System.out.println() serves the point of illustration.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name);
    for (char grade : grades)
        System.out.println("\t"+grade);
}
```

Comment: IT wont print grade when I do this